# Retrieve NSManagedObjectContext from NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've looked for this solution for a while, and I've always given up and found a work around, but does anyone know how do find the `NSManagedObjectContext` from an instance of an `NSManagedObject`?

I am currently using 3 contexts, and I would like to retrieve which context an instance of an object is in. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

have you tried

```
NSManagedObject *myObj; //reference in some way
NSManagedObjectContext *objContext = [myObj managedObjectContext];
```

?

Comment: you're welcome! The obvious solution is always the most difficult to find :p

Comment: lol, Thanks! me two ! .I can't believe I didn't find that before. thanks